# Mongoose - Create and Insert data to new collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Now I am a beginner in MEAN.io. I am using `mongoose` to insert data to DB. And I follow the code from [here.](http://modernweb.com/2014/04/21/mean-stack-a-quick-start-guide/)

In my `app.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var Factory = require('./module.factory.js');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/angular');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var dbCollection = db.collections;
var factory = new Factory(Schema,mongoose);
factory.createSchemas();
```

In `module.factory.js`

```
var Factory = function(Schema,mongoose) {
this.Schema = Schema;
this.mongoose = mongoose;
this.Item = null;

this.createSchemas = function() {

    var PersonSchema = new this.Schema({
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String, 
        city: String,
        state: String
    });
    this.Person = mongoose.model('Person',PersonSchema);
};

this.getPerson = function(query,res) {
    this.Person.find(query,function(error,output) {
        res.json(output);
    });
};

this.doLogin = function(query,res) {
    this.Person.findOne(query,function(error,output) {
    console.log(query);
        res.json(output);
    console.log(output);
    });
};
};
module.exports = Factory;
```

For inserting data:

```
app.post('/insert', function (req, res) {
req.addListener('data', function(message)
    {
        var command = JSON.parse(message);
        var document = {first_name: command.fname,
            last_name: command.lname,
            city: command.city,
            state: command.state};
        dbCollection.user.insert(document,function(err, records){
        res.send('Inserted');
        });
    });
});
```

It throws an error of `TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined`

But if I put `dbCollection.people.insert`, it works fine. Can anyone tell me how to create new collection and insert data into that.

Comment: do you have a `user` collection. Try `show collections` in console

Comment: Ya i have `user` collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did these changes to solve the issue:

Instead of creating collection in mongo shell, I put the following code in `module.factory.js`

```
this.Person = mongoose.model('Person',PersonSchema);
this.Person.db.collection("user", { .... } );
```